# Cannot resolve method 'getInstance()'

Tags: java, android

I was watching a youtube tutorial ([Firebase storage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-pkweD2s-Oo) and around 14 minutes I got this error code:

> Cannot resolve method 'getInstance()'

Can someone help me resolve it? I am pretty new to Java and have been watch tutorials to get the understanding right. I know this is a small detail, but it has been really frustrating.

```
package bfb.ess.myapplicationbfb;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class speakp extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button mRecordBtn;
private TextView mRecordlabel;

private MediaRecorder mRecorder;

private String mFileName = null;

private static final String LOG_TAG = "Record_log";

private StorageReference mStorage;


private ProgressDialog mProgress;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recordpage);

    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(); /*RIGHT HERE*/




    mRecordlabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recordlabel);
    mRecordBtn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.recordBtn);
```

Comment: Make sure the library is imported correctly.

Comment: You didn't import a `FirebaseStorage` class, and since compiler didn't complain about that, it means the class is a local class in the same package. Perhaps if you go look at *that* class, you'll see what it doesn't have a `static` no-arg method of that name.